# Local notification fired after deleting code

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am facing a weird problem with `UILocalNotifiation`. I was scheduling a local notification at 11:59 every night. Now, I have deleted that code from my project but I am still receiving that local notification every night at 11:59. I have tried to remove build from device, change device and clean derived data.

Comment: I also have the same issue , i don't know why local notification is being fired. As i deleted the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's actually standard iOS behaviour, since you schedule the notifications on iOS (the actual operating system). This means, that once you scheduled a `UILocalNotification`, it will sit in the operating system until it either fires or gets cancelled manually.

So, for your case, it sounds like you initially scheduled a number of notifications, these are now all sitting in the operating system waiting to fire. They won't go away when you change your code or delete the app, they will only go away f you either delete them or when they get fired.

In order to make sure, you don't receive any notifications that have been scheduled in the past, you can delete them using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

You can also get all notifications that are currently scheduled by your app and cancel them individually:

```
NSArray *activeNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (UILocalNotification *notification in activeNotifications) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelNotification:notification];
}
```